# Break and continue in GHCi debugger without use of breakpoints

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, ghci

In a traditional imperative debugger such as `gdb` it is possible to break into program executing with `SIGINT`, inspect the program state, and eventually resume execution.

While GHCi allows one to break into program execution at an arbitrary point with `-fbreak-on-exception`, attempting to resume execution with `:continue` will only lead to the interpreter continuing on with the exception handler and terminating the program,

```
> let main = findCureForCancer
> :set -fbreak-on-exception
> :trace main
[twiddle thumbs]
[why is this taking so long?]
[maybe something is wrong, I better see what it's doing]
^CStopped at <exception thrown>
_exception :: e = GHC.Exception.SomeException
                    GHC.IO.Exception.UserInterrupt
> :hist
...
[ahh, looks like this will just take a bit longer]
> :continue
[program should keep running]
```

Is it possible to break into execution and still resume execution after poking about a bit with the GHCi debugger?

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but possibly a workaround/interesting pastime while you wait for an answer: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/continue/0.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Continue.html

Comment: Another interesting possibility (I'd have to read up more to know whether it's also a promising one) is to do the following: setup signal handling that drops into a y/n prompt; if `no`, continue program; if `y`, throw an exception. If the exception is thrown, you'll fall into the debugger; you then might be able to step back, and continue from there, choosing `y` when you do, and resuming execution (after having poked around the debugger). Amusingly, reason why this _might_ work is because of the non-determinism of IO...

Answer (score 1):

I’m no GHC expert, but I am extremely confident that neither stable GHC nor the current GHC HEAD supports this.  The [manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) mentions nothing about it, and I’ve sourcedived [the current HEAD](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/tree/49857886538dcd0d4ecf51e9b5a116101d0cde0c) to make sure there’s nothing undocumented, commented out, or surrounded in an `#if FALSE`.  (If you’re interested, the currently-impemented GHCi commands are defined at [/ghc/InteractiveUI.hs:136](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/49857886538dcd0d4ecf51e9b5a116101d0cde0c:/ghc/InteractiveUI.hs#l136).)  Nothing has been posted on the [mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/ghc-devs) about this, at least since January 2013, and nobody has filed or closed a bug about it (see the [relevant bug tracker search](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/query?description=~debugger%5d)).

This sounds like it would be a useful feature to have – would you [file a feature request](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug)?